# When trying to use watir's #move_to method, getting "TypeError: expected Selenium::WebDriver::Element, got #<Watir::Button ...>"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir

After finding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685418/how-to-click-on-a-specific-coordinates-of-an-element) stackoverflow q/a about how to click on an element based on its coordinates, I'm trying to do so to click on a button I've discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37145927/watir-text-box-input-not-persisting-after-submitting-form-resetting-to-previous) question. Currently having to use the `cliclick` shell command for mac osx which is clunky. Anyway, here is the section of my Gemfile showing the watir related gems in order -- perhaps I've required more gems than is necessary?

```
gem 'selenium-webdriver'#, '2.45.0'
gem 'selenium'#, '0.2.11'
gem 'watir', '5.0.0'
```

Here's the full command I've run to get the error:

```
b = Watir::Browser.new #defaults to firefox
#...
element = b.span(:text => "Confirm Selection")
b.driver.action.move_to(element, 15, 15).click.perform
#=>
TypeError: expected Selenium::WebDriver::Element, got #<Watir::Button:0x39fe077c86d90f06 located=false selector={:id=>"id_280", :tag_name=>"button"}>:Watir::Button
    from /Users/davo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/mouse.rb:86:in `assert_element'
    from /Users/davo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/mouse.rb:69:in `move_to'
    from (irb):79
    from /Users/davo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/davo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/davo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Let me know if any more details would help.

System details:

- rails 4.0.0
- mac osx el capitan 10.11.1
- firefox 46.0.1
- selenium gem 0.2.11
- selenium-webdriver gem 2.53.0
- watir gem 5.0.0
- watir-webdriver gem 0.9.1

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that a `Watir::Element` is being passed to Selenium's action builder. The action builder only knows about `Selenium::WebDriver::Element`.

To convert a `Watir::Element` to a `Selenium::WebDriver::Element`, use the `wd` method:

```
element.wd
```

The `move_to` call should be:

```
b.driver.action.move_to(element.wd, 15, 15).click.perform
```